# Error deploying JSF 2, Spring 3.1 app on JBoss 7.1.1 >  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

Trying to deploy a JSF 2 app with Spring 3.1 + JPA 2 (Hibernte 3.6.8) into JBoss 7.1.1 AS. The app was working fine on tomcat 7. Now, I have already added and changed some configurations.

1. Added jboss-deployment-structure.xml >

> ```
>  <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
>       <deployment>  
>         <exclusions>
>         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
>           <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
>           <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
>           <module name="org.hibernate"/>       
>           <module name="org.javassist" />
>           <module name="javaee.api" />
>           <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
>           <module name="org.jboss.as.web" />
>           <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
>           <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
>           <module name="org.jboss.interceptor" />      
>          </exclusions>    
>       </deployment>
>     </jboss-deployment-structure>
> ```

*2.* Inside web.xml added these lines:

> ```
> <persistence-unit-ref>
>   <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
>   <persistence-unit-name>persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>      
> </persistence-unit-ref>
> ```

*3*. Inside applicationContext.xml, changed bean definition for entityManagerFactory by adding this property>

> ```
> <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
> value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
> ```

Now, do I still need to do something more than these which is obvious to you?
Because, while I am trying to deploy it from eclipse indigo SR2,
getting this >

```
14:10:32,046 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
14:10:33,054 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
14:10:33,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
14:10:36,375 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
14:10:36,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:10:36,432 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
14:10:36,462 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
14:10:36,587 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
14:10:36,714 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
14:10:36,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
14:10:37,043 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:10:37,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
14:10:37,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
14:10:37,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:10:38,792 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
14:10:38,833 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
14:10:39,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory F:\work\softwares\Application Servers\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
14:10:39,618 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
14:10:39,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
14:10:39,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment treasury.war
14:10:39,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found com.misl.treasury.ui.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called com.misl.treasury.ui.war.dodeploy
14:10:40,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:10:40,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "com.misl.treasury.ui.war"
14:10:40,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "treasury.war"
14:10:55,283 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
14:10:55,289 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
14:10:55,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for persistenceUnit
14:10:55,843 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
14:10:55,849 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
14:10:56,010 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."com.misl.treasury.ui.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."com.misl.treasury.ui.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "com.misl.treasury.ui.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JsfManagedBeanProcessor.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream from [Module "deployment.com.misl.treasury.ui.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 11 more

14:10:56,628 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."treasury.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."treasury.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "treasury.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: SAXException parsing vfs:/F:/work/softwares/Application Servers/JBoss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/treasury.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.BeansXmlProcessor.parseBeansXml(BeansXmlProcessor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.BeansXmlProcessor.deploy(BeansXmlProcessor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:175)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:394)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:322)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:281)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1459)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:903)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1196)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:555)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:289)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:94)
    ... 8 more

14:10:56,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:10:56,672 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 25527ms - Started 143 of 222 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
14:10:56,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "treasury.war" was rolled back with no failure message
14:10:56,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "com.misl.treasury.ui.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\""}}
14:10:56,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment com.misl.treasury.ui.war in 172ms
14:10:57,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment treasury.war in 395ms
14:10:57,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."treasury.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."treasury.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "treasury.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."com.misl.treasury.ui.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."com.misl.treasury.ui.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "com.misl.treasury.ui.war"

14:10:57,079 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"com.misl.treasury.ui.war\""}}}}
14:10:57,087 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
```

I have never tried JBoss before. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted `<module name="javaee.api" />` entry from jboss-deployment-structure and thus got rid of ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream error [because javaee api jar implements that class]. But, unfortunately, that was not all. It just cleared the path to show another error. This time, it is about hibernate.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate3/infinispan/SharedInfinispanRegionFactory

After searching a bit, it seems, it probably is a bug in JBoss 7.1.1. [Pity they won't release any newer version]

Anyway, I would be trying a hack from [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/197608). Looks like its a big journey towards an error free deployment!